# Working with ANT and facing an issue

Tags: java, xml, ant

```
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <if>
        <available file="../war" type="dir"/>
            <then></then>
        <else> 
            <mkdir dir="../war" />
        </else> 
    </if>
</target>
```

This is the code i am using to check if a folder exists, but getting the following error:

Cause: The name is undefined.

Action: Check the spelling.

Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.

Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

I have copied ant-contrib.jar in ANT_HOME/lib. where am i goin wrong?

Comment: Try to add taskdef to current project -  http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the example above, you can greatly simplify it:

```
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="../war" />
</target>
```

...since the `mkdir` task does nothing if the folder exists (see [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html)).

If you're asking how to use `if` and `then` in ant, I recommend picking another example since each action in Ant tends to have its own conditionals built in.